# Regular expression to validate time but exclude 0:00

Tags: regex

I'm not an expert to regular expressions, but I tried to validate the user input for a time field with it.

My current regex: /^([0-9]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/

It should validate anything positive between 0:01 and 9:59, but it also give positive return to 0:00.

Can you please help me to modify my regular expression to exclude 0:00?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can update as  /^([0-9]|0[0-9]):[0-5][1-9]$/

Comment: @NitinDhomse Doesn't this stop accepting, patterns ending with 0. Like 5:50, 05:50 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex you are looking for.

```
^((?!(0:00)|(00:00)$)0?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9])$
```

Uses the concept of negative look ahead. Using negative lookahead, you can say match everything except `0:00` and `00:00`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: but it will stop matching this time 5:50

Comment: @JagrutTrivedi It works fine for me. Please refer the link https://regex101.com/r/mY3JKn/2

Comment: but it is still returning true for 0:00

Comment: @JagrutTrivedi Hey! Thanks for pointing it out. The new one. https://regex101.com/r/mY3JKn/4

Comment: @EganWolf: oh thats right :-( ^(([1-9]):[0-5][0-9])|([0]:[1-5][0-9])|([0]:[0][1-9])$ should make it ... or?

Comment: @EganWolf Thanks for the update! I have changed the regex using negative look ahead! Here is the link for the same regex101.com/r/mY3JKn/6

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!0?0:00$)0?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```